# mod_rewrite .htaccess rewrite to subdir without change uri

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I tried to figure out a configuration for my server.
So my apache is in html where also my .htaccess is set.
In this html is also a www (where all web stuff is) dir and a subdomain dir.
Basically I want to rewrite all connections from my-domain.com to my-domain.com/www without changing the url.

So far I used

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)my-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^www/ /www%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

For normal file.html in html/www/file.html that works. So I see the content of /html/www/file.html and see my-domain.com/file.html

Once I use a php header to a sub dir in www the domain won't rewrite.
e.g. /html/www/sub/file.html gets my-domain.com/www/sub/file.html but my-domain.com/sub/file.html

I hope you'll find a better option.

Kind regards

Comment: Change last line to: `RewriteRule !^www/ www%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]`

Comment: So I changed that line. Thx for that. I identified my real Problem:
the redirect to direct filex like my-domain.com/subfolder/index.php works fine. Once the file drop out like my-domain.com/subfolder the redirect won't work an the url is my-domain.com/www/subfolder/

Maybe that's the way to find a solution